# input value formation with double quotation marks and single quotes

Tags: javascript

I have problem in the input "value".

```
$("#printCard").append("<input type='hidden' name='textCard' value='that aren't on the battlefield have flash. ' id='texting'>");
```

or JSON:

```
$("#demo").append("<input type='hidden' name='textCard' value='"+ infoCard.text +"' id='texting'>" );
```

Result:

```
<input name="textCard" value="that aren" t="" on="" the="" battlefield="" have="" flash.="" '="" id="texting" type="hidden">
```

The problem is double quotation marks and single quotes(**aren't..**).

This example:

```
The two options I have to save, double quotation marks and single quotes.
```

thank you all

Comment: escape the single quote in the value section \'

Comment: I have created a function doing regex, and it does not work.

Comment: did you try infoCard.text.replace(/'/g, "\\'")? please post your attempt and output from it

Comment: now... the problem is double quotation marks, dont work ".replace()".

look this: strInputString = vlr.replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace(/"/g, '\\"');

Comment: my solution is this:
strInputString = vlr.replace (/ '/ g, "\\'"). replace (/ "/ g," \ '");

change double quotes by single quotes. This is good for me.

Comment: From review: I voted to leave this question open because it has two components covered separately in [Escaping single quotes in JavaScript string for JavaScript evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087497/escaping-single-quotes-in-javascript-string-for-javascript-evaluation) and [How do I escape quotes in HTML attribute values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7753448/5217142). @Barmar 's jQuery answer to this question covers both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to support IE use **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)**. **TL** are strings that have an easier syntax and extra properties. Here's a comparison between **TL** and **SL** (**S**tring **L**iteral):

## Syntax

**SL:** Wrap strings in double or single quotes. If the content of string has quotes as well, they should either be escaped by being prefixed with a backslash:

```
\" and \'
```

OR use **[HTML entities](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html)**:

- `&lsquo;` or `&#145;` (**L**eft **S**ingle **QUO**tation mark)
- `&rsquo;` or `&#146;` (**R**ight **S**ingle **QUO**tation mark)
- `&ldquo;` or `&#147;` (**L**eft **D**ouble **QUO**tation mark)
- `&rdquo;` or `&#148;` (**R**ight **D**ouble **QUO**tation mark)

**Note:** These particular quotes represented by HTML entities are the curvy or *smart quotes* type and can only be used in plain text not code. The quotes used in code are straight, do not confuse them as universally accepted they are as different as a comma is to a period.

***[It's ok to use `&rsquo;` as an apostrophe - Unicode9.0.0, ch06, pg. 276](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch06.pdf)***

**TL:** Wrap strings in backticks, also called grave accent, On a QWERTY keyboard the key is located at the top left corner <kbd>`</kbd>.

`` `template literal` ``

---

## Concatenation vs. Interpolation

**SL:** A mess of single quotes, double quotes, and pluses:

```
var str = '<input id="'+ID+'" class="form-control">';
```

**TL:** Wrap variables ***and expressions*** in: `${...}`:

```
var str = `<input id="${ID}" class="form-control">`;
```

---

## Demo

```js
var infoCard = {
  text: "that aren&rsquo;t on the battlefield have flash."
};

$("#printCard0").append(`<input type='hidden' name='textCard' value='that aren&rsquo;t on the battlefield have flash.' id='texting0'>`);


$("#printCard1").append(`<input type='hidden' name='textCard' value='${infoCard.text}' id='texting1'>`);
```

```html
<main id='core'>

  <figure id='printCard0'></figure>

  <figure id='printCard1'></figure>

</main>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the object-based method, then you don't have to worry about special characters in HTML.

```
$("#printCard").append($("<input>", {
    type: "hidden",
    name: "textCard",
    value: infoCard.text,
    id: "texting"
});
```