# How do I write a SELECT .. WHERE IN clause using NodesJS and Postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, lambda

```
const deptCodes = ['001', '002', '003']

const getMembersQuery = {
   text: 'SELECT member_id FROM member_tbl WHERE dept_code IN ($1) AND delete_flg = 0',
   values: [deptCodes],
   rowMode: 'array'
};
    
const getMembersQuery Result = await client.query(getMembersQuery );
```

I am writing the above query but I am getting an error,
malformed array literal: "001,002,003"\

Comment: literals require single quotes `001,002,003` should be `'001','002','003'` i.e. inside the SQL itself it needs those singles quotes

Comment: Can you suggest how should I format the deptCodes values?

Comment: you need to embed single quotes into the string to be evaluated by SQL so that one variable `$1` can be interpreted as 3 separate stings each having a start and end single quote with commas between values. For this look at how you escape single quotes e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087497/escaping-single-quotes-in-javascript-string-for-javascript-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your depCodes in additional quotes

```
const deptCodes = ["'001'", "'002'", "'003'"]
```

or

```
const deptCodes = ['\'001\'', '\'002\'', '\'003\'']
```